# functools partials usage in Python - Logical Question

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm currently learning Python GUI tkinter library.
   I was creating a simple calculator , now I was using this partial from class functools, now from many sites I have learned that in order to use partial function, what you need to is that first you need to create a function with some sort of limited variables, for instance , like 3 variables

```
def sum(x , y , z):
    return x+y+z
```

now in order to use partial you need to do the following

```
sum_new = partial(sum , 2 , 3)
print(sum_new(5))
```

Basically executing above statement will automatically assign the value 2 to variable x in function sum and similarly 3 to y and 5 to z. 
**Problem :**
I am creating this calculator
Now in calling statement, I am calling the partial function without using parenthesis, why is that?

```
calculate = partial(calculation, empty_label , x1 , x2 , x3)

calculate_button = Button(Win , text = "Calculate" , activeforeground = 'red' , command = calculate)
calculate_button.grid(row = 4 , column = 0)
```

in above look at **command = calculate**

**Second Point**

```
def sum(Label , x1 , x2):
    n1 = (x1.get())
    n2 = (x2.get())
    result = int(n1) + int(n2)
    Label.config(text = "Sum is %d" %result)
    return

def calculation(empty_label , x1 , x2 ,x3):
    n3 = (x3.get())
    if n3 == '+':
        sum1 = partial(sum , empty_label , x1 ,x2)
        sum1()
```

Why here I need to use sum1() in parenthesis while in **point 1** I didn't need any parenthesis. Although we know that sum1 is not a function Kindly explain these points please.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am creating this calculator Now in calling statement, I am calling the partial function without using parenthesis, why is that?

Because the `command` argument requires a *reference* to a function. If you use parenthesis, you actually call the function and assign the return value to the command. The only time this works is if the function itself returns another function, like `partial` does.

In other words, this:

```
Button(..., command=x())
```

... is identical to this:

```
result = x()
Button(..., command=result)
```

When you use the `command` option, you are in effect giving the button the *name* of a function to be called when the button is clicked.

> Why here I need to use sum1() in parenthesis while in point 1 I didn't need any parenthesis.

Because when creating the label, you want to immediately perform the calcuation. Using the parenthesis is the difference between a reference to a function and actually calling the function.

There are times in programming when you need the reference, and times when you want the result of the function. The `command` option is one of the times when you need a reference.

Another way to think of it is like this: imagine if you ask your friend "what function do I use to add 5 and 3" and they answer "8". In this scenario you don't want them to do the addition for you, you want them to tell you the *name* of the function (`sum`, for example) so that you can do the calculation later.